# Сколько склонений имён существительных в русском языке?

Tags: орфография

Когда я посещал среднее учебное заведение, именуемое школой, меня не покидало ощущение, что шкрабы (школьные работники) - мошенники. Например, я твёрдо знал, что в русском языке (1) нет звуков, которые моделируются последовательностями символов "жь", "шь", "чь", "щь", зато (2) есть звуки, которые моделируются последовательностями "дь", "ть". Поэтому с моей точки зрения, последовательность символов "дочь" была непроизносима на русском языке, а каждая из последовательностей "доч" и "мать" была произносима на русском языке. Тем не менее, шкрабы уверяли меня, что в русском языке есть слова "дочь" и "мать", но нет слова "доч", зато слово "дочь" произносится по-русски "доч". Некоторые шкрабы давали мне "разъяснения" типа:

1) "Ты произносишь "сонце", а пишешь "солнце" Аналогично, ты произносишь "доч", а пишешь "дочь"." (Между прочим, украинцы произносят "сонце" и пишут "сонце"),

2) "Мягкий знак на конце слов "дочь" и "ночь" является грамматическим мягким знаком, который превращается в разделительный мягкий знак в слове "ночью".",

3) "Слово "дочь" - имя существительное женского рода третьего склонения с нулевым окончанием в именительном падеже единственного числа.".

Дополнение (от 13.06.2014)

Изредка в так называемой школе встречались учителя. Один из них строго спросил меня, почему я не слушаюсь классного руководителя. Я ответил, что не понимаю, почему на конце слова "мышь" следует писать мягкий знак. - Это хлам, - сказал Иван Иванович. А затем пояснил: "Много лет назад в русском языке производилась уборка. В результате этой уборки из слова "чижъ" убрали твёрдый знак, а в слове "мышь" забыли убрать мягкий знак".

Дополнение (от 15.06.2014)

Я побаивался Иван Ивановича, который бродил по школе как раненый пират. Поэтому я не спросил его, почему потом в слове "мышь" не убрали мягкий знак.

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке существует три склонения имен существительных. И правильно Вас уверяли шкрабы:мягкий знак имеет несколько функций.Можете здесь прочитать: http://rusgram.narod.ru/1173-1193.html

Comment: Прочитал в параграфе 1187:

"III склонение объединяет все существительные жен. р. с основой на парно-мягкую согласную или на шипящую, имеющую нулевую флексию в форме им. п. ед. ч. (орфогр. слова на -ь): область, радость, лошадь, рожь, тишь, ночь, мощь ..."

Comment: На самом деле склонений не три, а больше, но к этому вопросу это не имеет отношения. Тип склонения определяется системой окончаний.

Comment: Я тоже не сомневаюсь, что в русском языке число склонений имён существительных больше, чем три [склонения].

Comment: Теперь  у  вас  шкрабы  -  крайние !

Comment: Dear bernard.

Не суетитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: Согласен,  не  буду.

Answer (score 0):

СКАЗКА

Однажды, много лет назад, когда один маленький мальчик Ваня еще учился в школе,  им задали написать сочинение на тему "Кем я хочу стать". Ваня написал: я хочу стать "исвощикым". Все дети смеялись, а шкраб поставил ему двойку. Когда Ваня вырос, в извозчики его так и не взяли, и он стал учителем.

Comment: Милая София.

Скорей всего, "маленький мальчик" Ваня написал: "Йа хачу стать исвощыкам".

P.S. Я не планирую ни смеяться над Ваней, ни ставить ему  оценки.

Comment: Прообраз  Митрофанушки  тоже  стал  человеком  образованным.